# Google analytics iOS SDK 3.01 App speed not tracking

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, google-analytics

On device log I am receiving next info

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:414): Saved hit: {
        parameters =     {
            "&_u" = ".ojL";
            "&_v" = "mi3.0.1";
            "&an" = My App;
            "&av" = "0.88";
            "&cd" = Home;
            "&cd1" = Paid;
            "&cid" = "279893c8-3fe8-4264-b778-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            "&sr" = 320x568;
            "&t" = timing;
            "&tid" = "UA-432xxxx-x";
            "&ul" = en;
            "&utc" = "Get News";
            "&utl" = "Label My App";
            "&utt" = "3.207867980003357";
            "&utv" = "Screen My App";
            "&v" = 1;
            "&z" = 17701255915882718999;
            gaiVersion = "3.01";
        };
        timestamp = "2013-10-01 06:58:02 +0000";
    }
```

My code is next :

```
__weak CategoryCellTVC *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
    [GAI_DEFAULT send: [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createTimingWithCategory:GA_GET_NEWS
                                                              interval:@(interval)                                                                           name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Screen %@", weakSelf.title]
                                                                 label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %@", weakSelf.title]] build]];




GAI_DEFAULT is - #define GAI_DEFAULT [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]
```

Comment: Same here! It used to work with V2 but after upgrading it does not track.We must wait to for Google to fix it!

Comment: Same here but with 3.02. To docs imply that the interval is an NSTimeInterval but the header says that it wants an NSNumber and implies that it wants milliseconds instead of seconds like an NSTimeInterval. I have tried both with no luck. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/usertimings